# How to generate random vector with whole numbers and defined length in R?

Tags: r, vector, random

I've heard about

```
    set.seed(12)
    runif(12)
```

But I need Whole random numbers in my vector, for example, with vector length 5.

Like:`x<-c(rand,5)` (i know it's fake command, just for idea) to get `c = 9,0,4,3,5`

And also I would like to know how to get such vector only with number range between 15 and 34.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
R> set.seed(123)                     ## ensure it is reproducible
R> sample(15:35, 5, replace=FALSE)   ## you probably want unique draws
[1] 21 30 22 34 32
R>
```

For kicks you can sort it too:

```
R> set.seed(123)
R> sort(sample(15:35, 5, replace=FALSE))
[1] 21 22 30 32 34
R>
```

Comment: Cool thanks! May I also ask 1 more question? How to create random matrix 5x6 with whole  random numbers in it?

Comment: Wrap `matrix(..., 5, 6)`  around the `sample()` call.

Comment: And welcome to StackOverflow. It is customary to upvote (click on "up" triangle) and, in your case of the original author of the question, accept (click on "tickmark") a question if you found it helpful.

Comment: Ie `matrix(sort(sample(15:35, 30, replace=TRUE)), 5, 6)` but note that you now MUST use `replace=TRUE` as you can't get 30 distinct values from the sequence 15:35.

Comment: You also need `n=30`, not `n=5`.  You can't build a matrix of 30 elements from 5 elements.

Comment: Thanks again! I've voted up. Thank You! And the last question: is it possible to get random numbers in the matrix without any double values? Thanks very much anyway!

Comment: See what I wrote two comments ago. You cannot sample 30 unique values out of a set of 21 values.  Something got to give here.  Smaller matrix, larger sequence, or repeats.

Comment: Oh! True, my bad! Thanks a lot! You are the BEST!